# JSP Javascript, update java object value

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I'm currently trying to get the live value of a Java object in Javascript to fill up some progress bar.

Here is the code in the JSP file :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="server_ihm_web.server"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<style>
#myProgress {
width: 100%;
background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar1 {
width: 1%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#myBar2 {
width: 1%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#myBar3 {
width: 1%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar1"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar3"></div>
</div>
<%
    server serv = new server();
    serv.startServer();
%>
</body>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function move() {

    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar1");
    var elem2 = document.getElementById("myBar2");
    var elem3 = document.getElementById("myBar3");

    var id = setInterval(update, 100);

    function update() {
        elem.style.width = <%=serv.getBar1()%> + '%';
        elem2.style.width = <%=serv.getBar2()%> + '%';
        elem3.style.width = <%=serv.getBar3()%> + '%';
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

serv values are updated every few seconds but nothing changes for the progress bar.

I think it always take the base value of the object so everytime update() is called it will change the progress bar to the same value.

Is there a way to update the values of serv for the javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things that live on separate dimensions :)

Javascript executes in the browser and JAVA (JSP) on the server.

If your ideas was to have the jsp scriptlet execute in the user's browser, it is not going to happen.

If you need to update the page with a progress when it is already in the user's browser, you will have to implement some ajax call to get the updates on the background.

Comment: This question and this same answer comes up so often that I feel we need a well-known question and answer to mark these new ones as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP tags `<%= ... %>` are evaluated in the server, **before** the page is displayed the first time in a browser. So, the values of that tags are static, and don't change in each execution of the javascript functions.

For that values to change, you need to do a request to the server, and reload the page. To avoid reloading an entire page each time, you need to do an Ajax request to obtain a new value to display with Javascript.